# Not valid Doctrine2 mapping: The entity-class 'Downloads' mapping is invalid

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, mapping

I am trying to define a `OneToMany` bidirectional (to avoid a `ManyToMany` and extra table) and I am doing (I think) as docs says [here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional) but certainly I am missing something since I am getting this error after run the `doctrine:schema:validate` command:

> The association PlatformBundle\Entity\Downloads#identifier refers to the owning side field PlatformBundle\Entity\Identifier#downloads which does not exist.

This is how the entities looks like (just the relevant fields):

```
class Identifier
{
    /*
     * @var Downloads
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Downloads", inversedBy="identifier")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="downloads_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $downloads;
}

class Downloads
{
    /**
     * @var Collection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Identifier", mappedBy="downloads")
     */
    protected $identifier;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->identifier = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

This is a association where a download is assigned to many identifier. What I am doing wrong or missing here?

Comment: Try to use FQCN for `targetEntity` Annotation

Comment: @mblaettermann no changes, same result, this is weird

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mising an `*` in `Identifier` Class :

```
/**<- this one could cost you many hours :P
 * @var Downloads
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Downloads", inversedBy="identifier")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="downloads_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $downloads;
```